# Rewrite function

Tags: url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

I have a wordpress blog. I get url in blog like this,

```
    http://www.domain.com/2013/01/test19/page/2/
```

But I want my ur like this,

```
   http://www.domain.com/page/2/
```

So can we rewrite this url. I am newbie to .htaccess. I search many plugins like "WP htaccess control". But I dont know how to configure it. Kindly help me..

Thanks in advance ..)

Comment: What do you have for permalink settings at wp-admin->Permalinks->Settings?

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Settings->Permalinks`

Add this to Custom Structure: `/%postname%/`

**Update**

WordPress generates .htaccess-files for this. Just go to your root and activate the show invisable files on your computer.

Here is the htaccess for the structure:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Read more about permalink-structure [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But i want .htaccess code and it should be change "/year/month/date/postname/page" to simply "page" . Because i have infinite scroll wordpress blog. it fetch same posts. Thats why I ask here.

Answer (score 0):

... no, you can't do that at all.

WordPress, by default, *already uses `/page/#` as a permalink.*  Here's a better explanation with examples:

- `http://yoursite.com` - Blog home page showing page 1 of your blog
- `http://yoursite.com/page/2` - Showing page 2 of your blog
- `http://yoursite.com/2013/01/some-post-title` - Showing page 1 of "Some Post Title"
- `http://yoursite.com/2013/01/some-post-title/page/2` - Showing page 2 of "Some Post Title"

So really, the `/page/2` structure is already set up and used for something entirely different than what you're trying to do.  Also, infinite scroll (if you're depending on `/page/#` permalinks) should already work for the home page.

The only way to get `/page/2` on a *post* permalink is to manually add `<!--nextpage-->` in your post content.  The easiest way to display all of the post's information on a single page is to ... not do that.  Just remove the quicktag and the entire post will display.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. First let your know my problem. Kindly see my site http://www.newspull.com and http://www.newspull.com/2013/01/test19/ (this post fetch same thumbnails repeated from http://www.newspull.com/2013/01/test19/page/2)... so i want to rewrite above url. Hope you understand... Thanks !

Comment: if i rewrite this url http://www.newspull.com/2013/01/test19/page/2 to http://www.newspull.com/page/2 it will fetch second set of thumbnails...

Comment: No, I don't think you understand. `/2013/01/test19` is a single post/page. You don't use infinite scroll on a single post/page.  Your main site (http://newspull.com), however, *is* using infinite scroll on the front page correctly.

Comment: Mr.EAMann, I would like to create dazeddigital.com and mashable.com like single post. Thats why i do that. Or have you any idea for single post's infinite scroll with homepage thumbnails?

Comment: In that case, please ask a new question along the lines of "I would like to create an infinite scrolling single post in WordPress" because that's not what you're asking here. Your original question was about changing permalink structures to something that will not work in WordPress.

Comment: Also, as I said, your *homepage* already has infinite scroll turned on.  You want to turn on infinite scroll for an individual post/page that does not have a second page of content (http://www.newspull.com/2013/01/test19/page/2 does not exist!).

Comment: Really thanks for your advice. And am newbie for stackexchange so Apologies me. i try to set nextSelector (CSS) #navigation a:-nth child(3). but not work.. Could you advice me about nextSelector?

Comment: That's a separate question and should be [asked as such](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). Please avoid extended discussions in comments. This is a q&a site, extended discussions are better suited for forums like the [official support forum](http://wordpress.org/support).